# AddTransient or AddScoped for separate controller isntance per lisntener in .net core back ground application

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I have hosted a asp.net kesterl inside background service application and running multiple instances on different port of same controlled with some specific objects.
What I want's if when ever a hit comes on controller the parameter i passed in initial initialization should be used. sort of separate instance of controller per listner.
For test purpose I have tried the Singleton but it will result single instance.
Now I am checking which sort of instance (AddScoped or AddTransient) should I use for my scenario and how can i inject parameter during that.

My current code base looks like

```
    internal static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string listener, CommunicationChannelElement communicationChannelElement)
            {
//here i want how i can use addScoped or AddTransient with communication paramter
                return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton(communicationChannelElement)).
                ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseUrls(listener).
                UseStartup<Startup>());
            }
            
            
            
            
            private void StartBackGroundWebListener(CommunicationChannelElement communicationChannelElement)
            {            
               CreateHostBuilder(_objSettings, communicationChannelElement).Build().Run();//separate thread  using task parallel library          
            }
            
            
            public void StartAll()
            {
                    StartBackGroundWebListener("http://10.1.2.3:0001",communicationChannelElement1);
            
                    StartBackGroundWebListener("http://10.1.2.3:0002",communicationChannelElement2);
            
                    StartBackGroundWebListener("http://10.1.2.3:0003",communicationChannelElement3);
            }
            
            
            
            public class CallBackController : ControllerBase
            {        
    
                    private readonly CommunicationChannelElement CommunicationChannelElement;
    
                    public CallBackController(CommunicationChannelElement communicationChannelElement)
                    {
                        CommunicationChannelElement = communicationChannelElement;
                    }               
                ... 
                    
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have achieved it via following code

```
public class CallBackController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CommunicationChannelElement CommunicationChannelElement;
        public CallBackController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            CommunicationChannelElement = serviceProvider.GetService<CommunicationChannelElement>();
        }
        
        ....
}
  
  
  internal static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string listner, CommunicationChannelElement communicationChannelElement)
  {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(services => services.AddTransient(ctx => communicationChannelElement)).
              ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseUrls(listner).UseStartup<ComvivaStartup>());

            //return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton(communicationChannelElement)).
            //  ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseUrls(listner).UseStartup<ComvivaStartup>());
  }
```

if there is any improvement needed then please let me know